# How to inform user to use inline edit forms(which have to edit/save buttons)

Tags: design-patterns

I hope you are doing well. Actually clients need a form which supports inline editing(without any edit/save or submit button) just like [THIS](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Form-Elements-In-place-Inline-Editing-with-jQuery-TM-Editable/dotted-line-theme.html). The point is how can I guide user to use this form. If you guys have any idea/links of such website which such forms Please let me know. Thank You

Comment: I do not understand your question. But I do know that it is not related to design patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how these forms work? Or how to let the user know the form is interactive?

Using the ui you linked to, you need to run an ajax request sending the data to the server

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

when the onclick event fired on the green check mark icon..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

And then have a message box that says "All changes saved" liked google docs does.
[See google UI "saving" message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzIrP.png)

Not all forms work well this way. For instance if you do not want to save a record unless many fields are filled out correctly, you'll probably want a save button.

Comment: I'm asking how to guide users about the usage of these forms, as my client is not willing to use any button on this form.